# different rpm/port/return type velodyne VLP16

Tags: ros, vlp16, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I'm trying to figure out how to launch the velodyne driver if a vlp16 is using different parameters such as :
-Different RPM
-Different Port

- return type
- Destination IP address

I've been testing out : roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch pcap:="path_to_pcap_file" on "standard" pcap files, and I'm not even sure that's correct..

That would be for a pcap file, but I'm not convinced if I had mine connected on how to launch the driver with different configurations.

I've seen various questions for the 32 and 64 model, and even that was unclear so I figured I would just ask it here.

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232949/different-rpm/port/return-type-velodyne-vlp16/) by [Zepherus1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/26708/zepherus1984/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Several recently added parameters are missing as arguments to the installed launch scripts. I just opened [issue #90](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/90) to fix that.

Meanwhile, I suggest you create copies of `velodyne_driver/launch/nodelet_manager.launch` and `velodyne_pointcloud/launch/VLP16_points.launch` in some package of your own, then edit them to add the [desired parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver#Parameters). Don't forget to make `VLP16_points.launch` refer to your copy of `nodelet_manager.launch`. You might want to rename those files to avoid confusion.

If you want more detail, say so in a comment, and I'll try to make a complete example.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zepherus1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/26708/zepherus1984/) on 2016-05-08**:
Continued the discussion on the issue. Thanks !